# Problems with running Zest/Dot programs

Tags: java, eclipse, zest

I am trying to create a simple Java program, which uses the Zest framework in order to generate and display graphs from a .dot input graph. I have downloaded the whole gef4 framework into my eclipse and I have created two example java programs to test the visualization of a normal graph and a dot graph. The normal graph is working fine, but when I try to run the dot graph I end up with the following error (which doesn't make much sense for me)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/emf/ecore/util/Switch
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef4.zest.dot.DotGraph.<init>(DotGraph.java:37)
at test2.SampleDotGraph.main(SampleDotGraph.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.Switch
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 26 more
```

The java code is the following:

```
import org.eclipse.gef4.zest.dot.DotGraph;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class SampleDotGraph {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display d = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(d);
    shell.setText("GraphSnippet1");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    shell.setSize(400, 400);

    DotGraph graph = new DotGraph("digraph{ 1->2 }", shell, SWT.NONE);
    graph.add("2->3").add("2->4");
    graph.add("node[label=zested]; edge[style=dashed]; 3->5; 4->6");

    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        while (!d.readAndDispatch()) {
            d.sleep();
        }
    }
}

}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Read the error stack properly

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.Switch
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Application is not able to find the class Switch in URLClassLoader class in run() method.

Comment: So what should I do to get rid of this error? (obv i don't have the knowledge to sort it by myself)

Comment: Which JDK and JRE version you are using?

Comment: And what eclipse version are you using?

Comment: First check the required APIs are available on your included folder/path. If the APIs are there than check if you have included them while compilation compiler should be able to access it.